# No space left on device when trying to allocate swap?

Tags: swap, vagrant

Trying to allocate swap on an ubuntu vagrant box:

```
vagrant@vdd:~$ free -m 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2000          77        1700          21         221        1748
Swap:             0           0           0
vagrant@vdd:~$ df -h
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev              991M     0  991M   0% /dev
tmpfs             201M  3.1M  197M   2% /run
/dev/sda1         9.7G  9.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs            1001M     0 1001M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
var_www           233G   72G  161G  31% /var/www
vagrant           233G   72G  161G  31% /vagrant
v-csr-01990ea29   233G   72G  161G  31% /tmp/vagrant-chef/bb7bfafb0e147a5612bdc30388f928b8/roles
v-csdb-c3c049bff  233G   72G  161G  31% /tmp/vagrant-chef/c0dd3de78c9fe655c1d010aff45e22d0/data_bags
tmpfs             201M     0  201M   0% /run/user/1000
vagrant@vdd:~$ sudo fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
fallocate: fallocate failed: No space left on device
vagrant@vdd:~$
```

So if I understnad this correctly, `/dev/sda1` is the main partion used by the OS and it's full? is that correct?
Is it possible/good idea to use a different partition for swap?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are correct about the main drive being full. Additionally, you can verify the space using `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` commands respectively.

Regards to your choice of `swap` partition, you can add an additional disk to the volume group and use the free space to format logical volume as `swap`.

Below is a screenshot of using two disks. Please note that the `swap` partition was created later, even it exists on the first disk.

```
[root@remote-server ~]$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  <19.50g     0
  /dev/sdb1  vg00   lvm2 a--  <20.00g <2.00g
[root@remote-server ~]$ sudo vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  centos   1   2   0 wz--n- <19.50g     0
  vg00     1   2   0 wz--n- <20.00g <2.00g
[root@remote-server ~]$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root centos -wi-ao---- <15.50g
  swap centos -wi-ao----   4.00g
  home vg00   -wi-ao----  10.00g
  var  vg00   -wi-ao----   8.00g
```